# Pandas removing duplicate values column by column

Tags: pandas

How to go about removing duplicates column by column in a pandas data frame so that:

```
set1    set2    set3    set4
apple   apple   orange  orange
apple   orange  banana  orange
orange  banana  pear    
banana  banana  lemon   
pear            lemon   
grape           lemon
```

becomes:

```
set1    set2    set3    set4
apple   apple   orange  orange
orange  orange  banana  
banana  banana  pear    
pear            lemon   
grape
```

Comment: If you want the unique values from a column, you can always do `df['column_name'].unique()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
m=df.apply(lambda x:dict.fromkeys(x).keys())
pd.DataFrame(m.values.tolist(),index=m.index).T
```

Or a better way courtesy `@piRSquared`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {*df[k].dropna()} for k in df}, orient='index').T
```

---

```
     set1    set2    set3    set4
0   apple   apple  orange  orange
1  orange  orange  banana     NaN
2  banana  banana    pear    None
3    pear     NaN   lemon    None
4   grape    None    None    None
```

Comment: `pd.DataFrame.from_dict({k: {*df[k].dropna()} for k in df}, orient='index').T`

Answer (score 3):

#### `itertools.zip_longest`

```
from itertools import zip_longest

pd.DataFrame(
    [*zip_longest(*({*df[c].dropna()} for c in df))],
    columns=[*df]
)

     set1    set2    set3    set4
0  banana  orange  banana  orange
1   grape  banana   lemon    None
2    pear   apple    pear    None
3   apple    None  orange    None
4  orange    None    None    None
```

---

#### `collections.defaultdict` and `itertools.count`

```
# %%timeit
from collections import defaultdict
from itertools import count
i = defaultdict(count)

pd.DataFrame({c: {next(i[c]): v for v in {*df[c].dropna()}} for c in df})

     set1    set2    set3    set4
0    pear   apple  orange  orange
1   grape  banana   lemon     NaN
2   apple  orange  banana     NaN
3  banana     NaN    pear     NaN
4  orange     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way `pivot`

```
df.melt().dropna().drop_duplicates(['variable','value']).\
   assign(key=lambda x : x.groupby('variable').cumcount()).pivot(index='key',columns='variable',values='value')
Out[806]: 
variable    set1    set2    set3    set4
key                                     
0          apple   apple  orange  orange
1         orange  orange  banana     NaN
2         banana  banana    pear     NaN
3           pear     NaN   lemon     NaN
4          grape     NaN     NaN     NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `drop_duplicates` :

```
df.apply(lambda x : x.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True))
```

>

```
     set1    set2    set3    set4
0   apple   apple  orange  orange
1  orange  orange  banana     NaN
2  banana  banana    pear     NaN
3    pear     NaN   lemon     NaN
4   grape     NaN     NaN     NaN
```